# how to get id value from bootstrap 4 dropdown from table row?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

PHP Code:

```
<td>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            More
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="demolist">
            <a class="dropdown-item " id="achieve" value="<?php echo $value['user_login_id'] ?>">Achivements</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" id="skill" value="<?php echo $value['user_login_id'] ?>">Skills</a>
            <!--
            <a class="dropdown-item">Remove</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item">View Applicant</a>
            -->
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Here I have a dropdown button in each row where each dropdown has a list of achievements / skills. When clicking an achievement or skill I want to pass that row's id to ajax.

How should I send with ajax?

Answer (score -1):

Using this method you can easily get the dropdown value:

Pass the id or class by using the `.value` method.

```js
var submitForm = function() {
  var name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
  console.log(name);
}
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', submitForm);
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="name" class="name"><button class="btn" value="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solution like this code i think you enough smart to understand it but let me know if you cant get it.

```
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="demolist">
        <a class="dropdown-item achivementClass" id="achieve" value="value1">Achivements</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="skill" >Skills</a>            
        <a class="dropdown-item">Remove</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">View Applicant</a>            
    </div>

        This your script code
        <script>
          $(function() {
            $('.achivementClass').click(function(){      
            id =$(this).attr('value');
            console.log(id);              
                 });            
          });
        </script>
```